# Multi-language redirect with cookies in .htaccess? (without php)

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, multilingual, redirectwithcookies

I'm trying to a site to have language detection via the browser, but to also allow for a cookie to take priority over the automatic detection.

I'm still new at complex .htaccess rules, so I'm hoping for some help here. I don't know any php really though, so I'm hoping to avoid it.

This is what I'm looking to do:

I have 3 language options: german (de), english uk (en-gb), and the main site in english (en)
They correspond to: www.site.com/de/, www.site.com/uk/, and www.site.com/

1. Check if a language cookie has been set 
       1a) If set, redirect visitor to corresponding language directory.
2. If no cookie has been set:
   2a) Detect browser language and set
   language cookie (or default to english)
   2b) Redirect visitor to
   corresponding directory.
3. If user switches language via site language selection, update
   cookie.

Is something like this possible? Are there limitations to trying to do it this way?

Comment: For those that find this later:

Ended up going with Maxmind's mod_geoip2 and seems to be working as we hoped for.